Make openapi allof do inheritance in gradle
Need to create common response interface to use two versions of same api:
my issue is exactly same as in openAPI polymorphism - getting generated file to extend another schema
and there is response to use allOf: and REF_AS_PARENT_IN_ALLOF=true flag.
The problem is that i have gradle with groovy and couldn't find the way how to set the flag in gradle task in build.gradle file.
Is there any suggestions? Thanks.
EDIT#1:
Does anyone know equivalent for kotlin openapiNormalizer.set(mapOf("REF_AS_PARENT_IN_ALLOF" to "true")) for groovy (found - https://github.com/gradle/develocity-api-samples/blob/main/build.gradle.kts)?
or is it possible to specify parent in yaml:
    EmployeeBase:
      description: general employee information
      type: object
      x-parent: true

above not working.
